# Inverse of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a ring (associative, commutative, unital). Let $A[x]\equiv A^{(\mathbb{N})}$ be the ring of polynomials.

Assume that $(a_i)_{i=0}^n\subseteq A$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}$ are given such that $a_0$ is a unit and $a_i$ is nilpotent for each $i$, that is, $\exists n_i\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}$ such that $a_i\,^{n_i}=0$.

I am looking for the multiplicative inverse of $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_nx^n$, which I denote by $(b_i)_{i=0}^{m}\subseteq A$.

WLOG $a_0=1$ to simplify the expressions.

For the case that $a_1=1$ and $a_j=0\forall j>1$ I have solved the problem, and the solution is $$b_j := (-a_1)^j$$That was rather straightforward.

However, I am stuck on the general case.

It is clear that then $b_0=1$, $b_1=-a_1$, $b_2=a_1\,^2-a_2$ and recursively $$b_j = -\sum_{l=1}^{j}a_lb_{j-l}$$
However, how does one solve this recursion relation? In particular, how to find the formula for $m$, given $(n_i)_{i=1}^n\subseteq\mathbb{N}_{\geq0}$.

All I could come up with is that $b_j$ is a sum of summands of alternating terms, each of which is of the form $c\times a_{q}a_{q'}\dots a_{q^{'\dots'}} $ where $c\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q+q'+\dots+q^{'\dots'}=j$, and of course the term with $a_j$ has a minus sign and the term with $a_1\,^j$ is alternating with the parity of $j$.

Any help towards a general formula would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I do not think there is a general formula other than the recursive relation you have.